# collection.update query in mongo repository - spring mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have my collection student :

```
"_id" : 1,
"marks" : [
    {
        "name" : "maths",
        "score" : 78
    },
    {
        "name" : "physics",
        "score" : 88
    }
]
```

I can `$push` marks in the shell:

```
db.student.update({_id:1},{$push:{marks:{type:"english", score:99}}})
```

I want to write this inside the StudentRepository:MongoRepository as a custom query :

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends MongoRepository<Student,Long> {
    @Query()//how to write this ??
    public void append(Long studentId, Mark mark);
}
```

Comment: @Query is for selecting the documents. Update is a write operation which clearly requires a method within which you need to perform this operation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-template-update You can find $push example in the link i have pasted.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](https://dev.to/iuriimednikov/how-to-build-custom-queries-with-spring-data-reactive-mongodb-1802). Particularly the add to a nested array section. [CustomUserRepositoryImpl](https://github.com/mednikoviurii/spring-reactive-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/ch/andreevi/examples/spring/repositories/CustomUserRepositoryImpl.java) is the file you should look at. For your case you could do something like this:

StudentRepository

```
public interface StudentRepository {

    Mono<Student> addMarks (String studentId, String type, int score);
}
```

StudentRepositoryImpl

```
public class StudentRepositoryImpl implements StudentRepository {

    private final ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public StudentRepositoryImpl(ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Student> addMarks (String studentId, String type, int score) {
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(studentId));
        Update update = new Update().addToSet("marks", new Mark(type, score);
        return mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, Student.class);
    }
```

Student Model

```
@Value @AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    @NonFinal @Id String studentId;
    ...
    List<Mark> marks;
    
    ...
}
```

Mark model

```
@Value @AllArgsConstructor
public class Mark {

    String type;
    int score;

}
```

You can also do the implementation of StudentRepository directly in that file, I just followed the format in the guide.

Answer (score 1):

The query may be something like this :

```
@Query(value="{}", fields = "{'_id':? =1}")
public void append(Long studentId, Mark mark);
```